# Laravel & VueJS CORS Issue when trying to authenticate the user, even with the Cors middleware

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, cors

I'm trying to make an authentication gateway for my project and I keep on getting a cors error like this:

[cors error in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axlQg.png)

I am using Laravel for the gateway and Vue.js for the front end. I have made a cors middleware like shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1U74kJKy9XU)

Here's my login function in Laravel

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $loginCreds = $request->validate([
       'email' => 'required|string',
       'password' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    if(!auth()->attempt( $loginCreds )){
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Invalid login credentials.']);
    }

    $at = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

    return response()->json(['user'=>Auth::user(), 'access_token' => $at]);
}
```

And here's my call I make from the front end

```
        submitLogin() {
            let params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('email', this.email);
            params.append('password', this.password);
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
                data: params
            })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
```

That setup gives me the error but if I do the same call but I have the following in my login function it doesn't give me the error

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    return \GuzzleHttp\json_encode('ok');
}
```

I don't know what to do, any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

[Edit]

My Cors middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        //ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS"){
            //The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return response()->json('OK',200,$headers);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
}
```

**I use Laravel v7.14.1 and Laravel Passport for authentication**

Comment: Hi, Could you please share your CORS middleware, and you `app/Http/kernel.php` ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI I added it in the question

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: The edit worked, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Edit]**

Try to Update the header returned in `app/Http/Middleware/Cors.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors
{
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
     return $next($request)
       ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’)
       ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’, ‘GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS’)
       ->header(‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’, ‘X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization’);
   }
}
```

Source : [Medium](https://medium.com/@petehouston/allow-cors-in-laravel-2b574c51d0c1)

**[Alternative]**

I'm using `fruitcake/laravel-cors` package, you may give it a try

Setup steps

**1. Installation**

Require the fruitcake/laravel-cors package in your composer.json and update your dependencies:

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

**2. Publish Configuration**

Publish the config to copy the file to your own config: `config/cors.php`

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

**3. Usage**

- 3.1 Global usage

To allow CORS for all your routes, add the HandleCors middleware in the `$middleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

- 3.2 ONLY for API Routes usage

To allow CORS for your API routes, add the HandleCors middleware in the `$middlewareGroups` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php` class:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
     'web' => [
          // ...
     ],

     'api' => [
          // ...
          \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
     ],
];
```

Repo [link](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors)

Hope it helps

Comment: I can't install the package, composer gives me an error